# find all users with array of ids

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

hi i am using mongoTemplate and springboot and having user modal like given below, what i am doing is maintainig user friend followers and storing array of username in followers field which is an array, so that i can fetch all the friends using all that username and show it to the user, also i dont want to load all friends at once i want to paginate through.but how do i do it,i have no idea ,can someone please help me.

```
     @Data
     @Document(collection = "User")
     public class User {

     @Id
     private String id;
@Indexed
private String username;   // username of the user
@Indexed
private String name;       //name of the user
private List<String> followers;     // list of user following me
private List<String> following;     // list of user following

}
```

pseudo modal

```
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "username": "tom21",
      "name" : "Tom",
      "followers" : ["jerry","oggy","bob","jack]
    }
```

i want to search all documents with usernames present inside above followers array, how do i do it ??

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```java
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;

// somehow get an instance of a MongoTemplate and a User...

List<User> found = mongoTemplate.query(User.class)
   .matching(query(where("username").in(currentUser.getFollowers())))
   .all();
```

Comment: well, I do NOT see any pagination operation, @ZaihamM Code I think you could use code as above and add skip and limit(NOT all) to paginate the result.

List<User> found = mongoTemplate.query(User.class)
   .matching(query(where("username").in(currentUser.getFollowers()))).skip(skip).limit(pageSize)

Comment: thanks for your reply but its not working,i am tried your code

Comment: its returning empty list

Comment: what is returning `currentUser.getFollowers()`? are there any names in there? Also, followers is a list of "name" or "username"?